# Firebase auth/missing-email error, despite successful login

Tags: reactjs, firebase, vite

I'm encountering an issue in my React application using Firebase (v10.3.1) and Vite. I receive the following error intermittently:

```
Firebase: Error (auth/missing-email).
```

However, immediately after this error, the authentication process proceeds successfully, and everything works as expected. I've tried various troubleshooting steps but can't pinpoint why this error is occurring. Below is the relevant code from my login form component and an AuthWrapper component that utilizes the Firebase Context:
Login Form Component:

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  setErrorEmailMessage("");
  setErrorPasswordMessage("");
  setErrorAllMessage("");
  
  try {
    const loginError = await login(data.email, data.password);

    if (loginError) {
      const errorCode = loginError.code;
      const errorMessage = loginError.message;

      switch (errorCode) {
        case "auth/email-already-in-use":
          setErrorEmailMessage("Email already exists");
          break;
        case "auth/invalid-email":
          setErrorEmailMessage("Incorrect e-mail");
          break;
        case "auth/wrong-password":
          setErrorPasswordMessage("Wrong password");
          break;
        case "auth/weak-password":
        case "auth/invalid-password":
          setErrorPasswordMessage("Password should be at least 6 characters");
          break;
        case "auth/user-not-found":
          setErrorEmailMessage("User not found");
          break;
        case "auth/missing-email":
          console.error("Login error1:", errorMessage);
          break;
        default:
          setErrorAllMessage("ERROR");
          break;
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Login error:", error);
  }
};
```

AuthWrapper Component:

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  console.log('Hi there ');
  console.log(email);

  try {
    const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );
    const firebaseUser = userCredential.user;
    fetchUserData(firebaseUser);
    console.log("Success login!");
    return null; 
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution! The problem is that I specified  in the form and in the Login button itself I also specified onSubmit, because of this 2 times the function was called. You just need to specify input type Submit and that's all